# Django: how can i change cat_id to cat_slug without deleting database?

Tags: python-3.x, django, sqlite, django-models, slug

Cat_id in sqlite is int right now. Is there any way to change it to slug without deleting whole database? I've already deleted it while changing men_id to slug and it was pretty long action.

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse


class Men(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Заголовок')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True, db_index=True, verbose_name='URL')
    content = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name='Текст Статьи')
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos/%Y/%m/%d", verbose_name='Фото')
    time_create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Время публикаци')
    time_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Время изменения')
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='Видимость на сайте')
    cat = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='Категория')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post', kwargs={'post_slug': self.slug})

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Известного мужчину'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Известные мужчины'
        ordering = ['title']


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True, verbose_name='Название каатегории')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True, db_index=True, verbose_name='URL')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('category', kwargs={'cat_slug': self.slug})

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Категорию'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Категории'
```

Comment: I think it makes sense to *first* create an *extra* field, then write a data migration to do the mapping, and *then* (so in a separate migration) remove the "old" column.